# Javascript: Infinite loop for import and script type error

Tags: javascript, python, webserver

I'm running a website on `localhost:8000` and I'm currently in an infinite loop for fixing this problem. This is the line for using the javascript file in my html file:

```
    <script type="module" src="./scripts/main.js"></script>
```

I set the type to `"module"` to use `import` in the JavaScript file. But I get this error:

```
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/plain". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

When I use `text/javascript` as the type, I can't use `import` in the JavaScript file anymore. So, I need to use `type="module"` and now I'm in a **infinite loop**.

package.json:

```
{
    ...
    "main": "main.js",
    "type": "module",
    ...
```

For the webserver I use python:

```
import http.server
import socketserver

class Handler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, directory="PATH_TO_HTML_FILE", **kwargs)


handler = Handler
handler.extensions_map.update({
    ".html": "text/html",
    ".css": "text/css",
    ".js": "text/javascript"
})
httpd = socketserver.TCPServer(("localhost", 8000), handler)
print(handler.extensions_map[".js"])
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Output:

```
text/javascript
```

So, you can see it should be correct.

Comment: You need to fix your webserver configuration so that files with `.js` suffix get MIME type `test/javascript`

Comment: If the console no longer throws a module related error, I'd guess that the infinite loop problem is related to the code itself.

Comment: @Barmar I believe you mean `text/javascript`, not `test`.

Comment: @Barmar okay, thanks. How would I do that?

Comment: I edited the question. I still have the problem, even I configurated the webserver.

Comment: Are you really using Python for static files? They're usually handled directly by Apache. I'm not really familiar with configuring this, but I think it goes in `.htaccess`.